# Delegate property with different type in Swift

Tags: swift

Ok so we have `UIScrollView` declaration:

```
protocol UIScrollViewDelegate: NSObjectProtocol { ... }
class UIScrollView: UIView {
    ...
    weak var delegate: UIScrollViewDelegate?
    ...
}
```

And then `UITableView` with `delegate` variant?

```
protocol UITableViewDelegate: NSObjectProtocol, UIScrollViewDelegate { ... }
class UITableView: UIScrollView {
    ...
    weak var delegate: UITableViewDelegate?
    ...
}
```

How Apple did this? When I do my

```
protocol MyScrollViewSubclassDelegate: NSObjectProtocol, UIScrollViewDelegate { ... }
class MyScrollViewSubclass: UIScrollView {
    ...
    weak var delegate: MyScrollViewSubclassDelegate?
    ...
}
```

I get **Property 'delegate' with type 'MyScrollViewSubclassDelegate?' cannot override a property with type 'UIScrollViewDelegate?'**.

Comment: What if you set your subclass to UITableView. class MyScrollViewSubclass: UITableView

Comment: Did you try protocol extensions in Swift 2.0?

Comment: My question is rather how Apple did this "magic", not how to design "workaround".

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon this a few times and the only work-around I found was just calling my property something else like customDelegate or whatever you like.

It would be neat indeed to be able to just call it delegate but hey!

Comment: Same here. But... today I realized Apple does it. And I'm just seriously curious how!

Comment: Have you tried `unowned(unsafe) var delegate: MyScrollViewSubclassDelegate?` ?
This is what I see in UITableView source.

Comment: I see `weak` there. Either `unowned` cannot be applied to non-class type `MyScrollViewSubclassDelegate?`.

Answer (score 2):

MyScrollViewSubclass has the delegate property of UIScrollView because it's subclass of UIScrollView.

As `delegate` is already defined by UIScrollView, you cannot define the same property name with a new type.

Change the variable name `delegate` to `myDelegate` (or something else) and it should work.

Comment: This is all it took for me to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working but I do not like the solution very much since it throws away type checking.

What I did was this. In my base class I declared the delegate as

```
weak var delegate: AnyObject? = nil
```

Then, when I want to call a method on the delegate I do

```
if let delegate = self.delegate as? MyBaseClassProtocol { delegate.myMethod() }
```

In my subclass I can then also do the same kind of thing

```
if let delegate = self.delegate as MySubclassProtocol { delegate.mySubclassMethod() }
```

As I say, it works, but I don't like it much. Throwing away the typechecking is not to be done lightly in my opinion. I am only sharing in the hope someone with stronger Swift skills can improve upon it, or correct it.