# Change superclass property type on swift

Tags: swift, properties, superclass

In a super Class called `TableViewCell` I have a property

```
class TableViewCell {
    var model: AnyObject?
}
```

In a class called `CountryTableViewCell` I wrote this code

```
class CountryTableViewCell : TableViewCell {

    var model:[AnyObject]? {

        didSet {
            // do some stuff
        }
    }
}
```

and I got this error

> property model with [AnyObject]? cannot override a property with type
>   Anyobject?

Is it not possible to change the property model to an array?

Comment: try with override before var model:[AnyObject]

Comment: does not work, same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot use like that. Also `AnyObject` should be replaced by `Any` if using Swift 3.

You can change your code as below:

```
class TableViewCell {
    var model: Any?
}

class CountryTableViewCell : TableViewCell {

    override var model: Any? {
        didSet {
        }
    }
}
```

Now if you want to get an array of the model in didSet then you can type cast it as below code.

```
class CountryTableViewCell : TableViewCell {

        override var model: Any? {
            didSet {
               if let arrModel = model as? [Any] {
                  // Do Stuff...
               }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly thank you. But I am using swift 3 and I used  AnyObject, not Any. Is this an issue ?

Comment: @J.Doe from Swift 3 onwards you will need to use Any instead AnyObject.

Comment: Do you have any reference? Here they say it's not the same https://medium.com/@mimicatcodes/any-vs-anyobject-in-swift-3-b1a8d3a02e00#.11oyobtcw

Comment: @J.Doe Yes it's not the same but it's better to use it. As AnyObject has different purposes on Swift 3. Read this https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0116-id-as-any.md

Answer (score 0):

No the property's type cannot be changed. If this is allowed, it would violate type safety by:

```
let subcell: CountryTableViewCell = CountryTableViewCell()
let supercell: TableViewCell = subcell
supercell.model = "anything that is not an array" as NSString
let wrong = subcell.model   // not an array!
```

[@ParthAdroja's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42671611/224671) showed a runtime workaround for this. You won't get an array at compile type, but at least you can ensure you have an array at runtime.

In principle if the property is read-only this specialization in subclass should work (it is same as restricting the return type of a function), but it doesn't work as of Swift 3. Anyone care about this can file an SE request to the Swift team ☺.

(Additionally, Apple [do have some magic to make it work with bridged Objective-C classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31704480/delegate-property-with-different-type-in-swift), but we don't know what it is yet.)